# Chrome on stock Android 4.4.2 redirects to ad sites

Tags: android, google-chrome, malware

I have an issue with my Tesco Hudl2 tablet. I've just bought the appliance, I haven't installed any apps from outside the Play Store (and never do, usually). During normal navigation, I often encounter unsolicited redirects to ad sites (such as cityaspix.com) regardless of the site I'm on. It has happened basically everywhere I go to (arstechnica.com, guardian.co.uk, even here on Stack Exchange... so all legit sites).

I have searched a lot for solutions to this issue, but to no avail. This also happens for example in Facebook's app's internal browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem on both iOS and Android devices where these ads seem to "auto-click" themselves. Very annoying. This isn't limited to just your tablet, it's all mobile devices for the most part. You can read more about it here:

http://techcrunch.com/2014/01/06/shady-app-install-ads-are-automatically-redirecting-mobile-users-to-app-store-google-play/

http://digiday.com/publishers/shady-mobile-app-install-ads/

Comment: There is a difference though: while the reported issues concern ads on mobile gaming, the ads I see are all porn-related. On occasion, AliExpress.

Comment: Maybe not necessarily the same ads as the game related ones, but possibly using the same tactic? You may even want to look into using a different DNS server such as OpenDNS (I use it on every one of my internet-connected devices) that can filter out some of these bad sites and redirects. Have you run a virus scan on your tablet? I believe they have AVG for Android?